# React - Cannot read property 'commentDelete' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

I am working with the React tutorials, and having issues trying to set a delete button on a comment to return the ID of the comment to delete.

I think its because of the map function has cut off my scope to the props , but unsure of how to get around this.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'commentDelete' of undefined

```
  handleDelete: function(commentId)
  {
      alert('HANDLE')
      //e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
          url: this.props.url,
          dataType: 'json',
          type: 'delete',
          data: commentId,
          success: function(data) {
              this.setState({data: data});
          }.bind(this),
          error: function(xhr, status, err) {
              console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
          }.bind(this)
      });
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="commentBox">
        <h1>Comments</h1>
        <CommentList onCommentDelete={this.handleDelete} data={this.state.data}/>
        <CommentForm onCommentSubmit={this.handleCommentSubmit}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var CommentList = React.createClass({
render: function() {
    alert('TEST');
    var commentNodes = this.props.data.map(function (comment) {

        return (
          <Comment onCommentDelete={this.props.onCommentDelete} commentId={comment.commentId} author={comment.author}>
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

      {comment.text}
    </Comment>
  );
});
```

UPDATE: 
The bind(this) did the job, now I have to go understand why :) Thanks

alternatively I also got it to work like so ...

```
var CommentList = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        var deletefunc = this.props.onCommentDelete;
            ^^^^^^^^^^
        var commentNodes = this.props.data.map(function (comment) {
            return (
              <Comment onCommentDelete={deletefunc} commentId={comment.commentId} author={comment.author}>
          {comment.text}
        </Comment>
      );
    });
    return (
      <div className="commentList">
        {commentNodes}
      </div>
    );
  }
  }
);
```

Comment: post your code totally

Comment: bind(this) to the map function. (If you don't know what I mean ask me to post a complete answer, I think you just forgot about it)

Comment: sure, use `}.bind(this));` at the end